# Multiple if functions that won't generate a too many argument error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

The following formula worked until I added the last IF statement. I understand at the core what this errror means due to researching it. However, I cannot figure out what I need to do to keep the functionality and get this formula to work.

What I am wanting to check is three specific cases. All related to comparisons of today's date.

1. If the cell is less than today's value.
2. If the cell's value is between 1-10 days before today's date.
3. If the cell's value is greater than 30 days from today's value.

Formula:

`=IF(E13<TODAY(),"Schedule CPD Presentation asap and consider changing sales start date",IF(AND(E13>=TODAY(),E13>TODAY()+10),"Query 1","Query 2"),IF(E13>TODAY()+30,"Plan out your CPD Presentation according to the Hold CPD Presentation date listed."))`

Does anyone see how I can resolve this based on what I am looking to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst Excel does indeed provide the capability to provide complex formulae by nesting functions within other functions it can be difficult, as you have found, to modify these. In organisations, these difficulties get magnified when the original developer of a spreadsheet moves on or leaves. It is little wonder that IT professionals often throw their hands up in horror when they discover that Excel is being used to manage some important aspect of a business.

One observation of your formula is that the nested `IF`'s contain quite a lot of parameters: for example the time ranges "before today" (expressed as `E13<TODAY()`), "between 1 and 10 days", etc and the associated outcomes such as "Schedule CPD presentation...", "Query1", etc.

If these same parameters are used elsewhere in the spreadsheet and, for some reason, they need to change it can be difficult to identify all the formulas that require changing. Errors can easily occur by missing something that needs to be changed or by making inconsistent changes. Examples of changes are things like: "between 1 and 10 days"  gets changed to "between 1 and 15 days" or split into "between 1 and 5 days" and "between 6 and 10 days". Even if a parameter is not scattered all over a workbook just adjusting a complex formula containing a lot of parameters can be less than straightforward (as you found).

Fortunately, embedding parameters within complex formula is a practice where there is often room for considerable improvement.

In your particular example, a simple parameter table showing the outcomes for different time ranges can be used. This makes the parameters immediately visible within the spreadsheet (rather than being hiding them in formulas). It allows the type of changes noted above to be made quickly and easily. Some of the "tricks" involved include

- using named ranges (helps reduce referencing errors when the number of parameters changes)
- use of `INDEX/MATCH` rather than the `VLOOKUP` function (Google it)
- use of the *match_type* argument in function `MATCH` (see the [MATCH function documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a))

This approach is shown below. It is offered as an example of how a different approach can, perhaps, make things more transparent and easier to maintain into the future. Compare the parameter table (in range `A1:C5`) and the formula in cell `E15` of the screenshot below with the formula you were trying to edit. Which is easier to understand? Or more pertinently, which is easier for someone else to understand?

[image: Screenshot of paramaterised approach]

The use of 999999 in cell A2 is another trick. It is the limit on how far into the future (in days) is valid for the first outcome ("Plan out..."). 999999 days is, of course, over 2500 years so it is a limit that is unlikely to be breached!

Comment: I love this solution! I used the cell ranges instead of "Outcomes" and "TimeValues"...I was unsure how you did that. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use the Name Manager. Access it from Formula menu on ribbon, Defined Name group. You can use it to give a range (such as $A$2:$A$5) a name (such as Time Values). You can then use these names in formulas in place of the more usual range reference.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(E13<TODAY(),"Schedule CPD Presentation asap and consider changing sales start date", IF(AND(E13>=TODAY(), E13<=TODAY()+10), "Query 1", IF(E13>TODAY()+30,"Plan out your CPD Presentation according to the Hold CPD Presentation date listed.", "Query 2"))`

“Query 2” was occupying where you would nest your final If statement. Place “Query 2” in the Else position of the final If statement.  Also, your formula wasn't consistent with your 2nd bullet point but I believe I changed the formula to meet your goal.